# Using appsettings.json for Entity Framework database configuration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, appsettings

I'm using .NET exclusively for Entity Framework's elegant handling of migrations. I have a working project with an EF schema. The part I now need is to move the DB connection string into configuration.

All I have so far is the following:

```
public partial class EfContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=...;Username=...;Password=...");
        }
    }
}
```

There is no other code apart from the entity definitions and migrations (no Startup class or HostBuilder stuff at all).

Can any kind soul instruct me in the simplest way to move the string into `appSettings.<env>.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using EF Core, then you can use the [design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) and implement the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface to wire-up the `DbContext` as you need it.

Otherwise the equivalent interface for EF6 is [`IDbContextFactory<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbcontextfactory-1).

For both what will happen is that the migration tool will scan the assembly for that interface and use it as an entry point.

I hope this example can help you https://github.com/binick/samples/tree/master/src/raw-ef-migrations/ops/sql-server/design

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

var configuration = builder.Build();

var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");

var db = new EfContext(connectionString);

//use the DbContext...



public partial class EfContext : DbContext
{
    private string connectionString;

    public EfContext(string connectionString): base()
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

the appsettings.json file would look like this

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "data source=localhost;initial catalog=ConsoleApp59;persist security info=True;integrated security=true"
  }
}
```

And would be configured to "Copy to Output Directory"

[image]

And you'll need to add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` NuGet package.